# What am I doing wrong in my drawing of a Quad in LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

If I switch GL_QUADS to GL_TRIANGLES and remove the last point, the triangle renders fine.
However, changing it back to GL_QUADS and adding another point just leaves me with a black screen. So what do I do?

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

public class Main {
public Main() {
    this.start();
}

private void start() {  
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640,640));
        Display.setTitle("FPSTest");
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(-10, 10, -10, 10, -1000, 1000);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glRotatef(0, 1, 1, 1);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
//          GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
        {
            GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex3f(0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
            GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            GL11.glVertex3f(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
        }
        GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        Display.update();
    }

    Display.destroy();
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    new Main();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertices of a quad must be coplanar. The four vertices you specified are not, and according to [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitives#Quads), the results are undefined in this case (which is probably the reason for the blank screen).

Here's a [tool](http://www.easycalculation.com/analytical/cartesian-plane-equation.php) to help you find the plane equation, so you can choose a coplanar 4th point. Your first 3 points form the equation `-9x -9y +9z + 27 = 0`, so one example of a suitable point is:

```
GL11.glVertex3f(2.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: ["Coplanar"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coplanarity) means that all points must be in the same plane.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that. I'm still not sure which point it is though.

Comment: Jeez, I need to get some sleep. Thanks for the help, and I'll say this answer is the answer once StackOverflow lets me choose it.

Comment: Actually, it can be any of them. Any arbitrary 3 points form a plane, the 4th is the only one constrained by it.

Comment: Three points are always coplanar to one another. The fourth point is not in the same plane as the first three.

Comment: I didn't mean that order mattered. xD. I suppose I wasn't writing as technically as I'd meant to.

Answer (score 2):

As mgibsonbr mentioned, the vertices are non-coplanar. He posted a nice tool to help you as well.

This may also help you.

If four vertices, with  components; 1 <= n <= 4 are coplanar then the determinant of the matrix:

```
|x1  y1  z1  1|
|x2  y2  z2  1|
|x3  y3  z3  1|
|x4  y4  z4  1|
```

will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP), all triangles are coplanar ;)